# Редирект пользователей с мобильными устройствами

Tags: php

На сайте для дэктопа и мобильной версии координально разная структура, по этому вместо адаптивной верстки хотелось бы редиректить на мобильную версию, как это сделать в интернете много вариантов, но вопрос у меня такой - каким более адекватным способом это сделать чтобы не пострадала сео оптимизация и скорость самого редиректа например=) Есть три варианта - js, htaccess и php redirect.

Делаю сайт на Yii2 может в этом фрейме есть какое то решение (я не нашел).

Comment: используйте `htaccess` (если сможете)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `.htaccess` прописывая маршруты. Можно определить какое устройство:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?i:midp|samsung|iphone|android)
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://m.domain.com/ [R=301]
```

В Yii2  есть модули, там делаете модуль мобильной версии. Напомню что модуль - это абстрагированная часть вашего приложения, как раз таки там и делайте вашу мобильную версию.

Comment: спасибо за ответы, применю модуль в yii и редирект через htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Через php оптимальнее представляется. Почему.

- Работает вне зависимотси от сервера - nginx, apache и прочее - где php запускается, то и ладно;
- Наибольшая гибкость и оптимальность нагрузки - загоняется в массив нужное, ставится вверх точки/точек входа - и никакой нагрузки, быстро, удобно, чисто, управляемо и расширяемо;
- Есть возможность производить дополнительные манипуляции в очень удобном виде, с использованием всего инструментария php - например, загонять что-то в буфер и делать там, что угодно до последующей выдачи;
- Одновременно можно предусмотреть запись статистики в самых широких реализациях;
- Можно оформить ввиде модуля и подключатть, как угодно и с какой угодно "дискретностью";
- Нет дополнительной нагрузки на htaccess, который, по-любому, лучше не перегружать;
- и т.д.

+) - не зависит от движка и особенностей его реализации - универсальность)

Comment: Когда речь идет о простом редиректе на мобильную версию, то лучше использовать веб-сервер.

Comment: @Mully В php также user-agent берется - впрочем - мнения разные, как и должно быть)

Comment: Ну прост логику редиректов лучше вынеси в веб-сервер, а php чтобы занимался дальнейшим роутингом

Comment: @Mully тоже верно, но все-таки за универсальность - а именно - на сервере делать только то, что по-другому будет затруднительно и неоптимально - а так - любой модуль можно использовать на разных проектах, и со временем совокупное качество растет - все оттачивается и полируется - без привязки к особенностям движков и самих серверов.

Comment: Ну я  с вами тоже согласен, ваше решение тоже будет вариантом, так же как и мое, впринципе они "одинаковые", поэтому я однозначно +1 вам поставлю))

Comment: @Mully И я согласен) Взаимно)